# Simulate user clicks

Tags: java, android, sdk

How to activate a tap on the screen in AndroidStudio Java (how do autoclickers work, how do they simulate clicks)? I need to organize a simulation of tapping at certain coordinates on the phone screen.

How click simulation works?

Comment: simulate tapping on the screen with adb might be ok for you?

Comment: If adb does not require root, then it is suitable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `adb` to simulate tapping the screen:

```
adb shell input tap x y
```

where `x` and `y` are coordinates of the point in the screen to tap. You can find those coordinates by enabling and extra info in the device

```
adb shell settings put system pointer_location 1
```

and

```
adb shell settings put system pointer_location 0
```

to disable these extra info

Comment: Does ADB requires root?

Comment: all the commands I posted doesn't require root. You can use them on emulator or real phone

Comment: I have `Permission denied` for this commands

Comment: mmm very weird that those commands do not work if you invoke them through the terminal

Comment: I must use `Runtime().exec("adb shell...")` or what?

Answer (score 1):

You can use "Maestro by mobile.dev". I'm using this and i can do anything with onTap option.

Comment: Autoclickers work on top of other windows, but this thing is for testing.  How to do it?